# Rails polymorphic association with multiple foreign keys and database constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations, multi-table-inheritance

I've been playing with Multi-Table inheritance and database constraints. I know that Rails philosophy is to handle constraints in the code and not in the database but I'd like to do both. I also know about polymorphic associations but they don't let you enforce constraints.

So here is my scenario, instead of having `imageable_type` and `imageable_id` like in the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), I'd like to have `employee_id` and `product_id` (in my case I will only have two foreign keys). That lets me create a constraint like explained [here](http://dan.chak.org/enterprise-rails/chapter-10-multiple-table-inheritance/).

But now, I have a problem, I need to create a conditional relation and rails doesn't seem to provide anything for that. I would need an `imageable` relationship that is either linked to a product or an employee depending on which field is filled.

Any suggestion how to do that in Rails? I know how to do the constraint in SQL, my question is really how can I implement this polymorphic relation in Rails.

Once again, I know how to do that without database constraints, but database constraints are the very point of my question :)

Comment: You want each picture to be linked to exactly ***1*** employee or product (xor)? Never more? Require at least one of both? Never both?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to allow at most ***1*** reference to either `employee` or `product`:

```
CREATE TABLE picture (
  picture_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, picture text NOT NULL
, employee_id int REFERENCES employee
, product_id int REFERENCES product
, CONSTRAINT employee_xor_picture
       CHECK (employee_id IS NULL OR product_id IS NULL)
);
```

- `employee_id` and `product_id` each [reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) the PK of the respective tables and can be NULL.
- The [CHECK constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) `employee_xor_picture` enforces that at least one of both stays NULL at all times.

It does *not* enforce that one of both is `NOT NULL` - it's typically more convenient to allow pictures that are not yet assigned, but that really depends on your requirements. To enforce that, too:

```
    CHECK (employee_id IS NULL AND product_id  IS NOT NULL OR
           product_id  IS NULL AND employee_id IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but my question is about the Rails implementation. How do to a polymorphic relation with this design and constraint. In rails, polymorphic normaly have a `imageable_type` and `imageable_id` and won't work without them.

Comment: @kalema: Oh, sorry. I guess I misunderstood `"but database constraints are the very point of my question"` before you updated the question. I can't help with the Rub syntax here.

Comment: I know, I realized my question was ambiguous, that's why I edited. Thanks for your help though!